# Xcode - Remove or change color of bracket match

Tags: xcode, xcode15

In the Xcode editor there is a feature that highlights the starting / ending brace of a function. I find this extremely distracting and often lose the input caret position when using the Default (Dark) theme. Is there a way to modify the color or disable this feature?

Using Xcode 15.

Thanks for any tips!